# Show the associated model object fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, fastjsonapi

I have a model `Organisation`. This model has_many `organisation_branches`.
The `organisation_branch` has the address details in which the `city_id` is present, which refers to the city table.

organisation.rb:

```
class Organisation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :organisation_branches
end
```

organisation_branch.rb

```
class OrganisationBranch < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organisation
  belongs_to :city
end
```

organisation_serializer:

```
class OrganisationSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :id,:org_id,:organisation_name

  has_many :organisation_branches
end
```

I need to display the Branch details with the name of the city retrieved from the city table. All this needs to be shown when an organisation is viewed.

Comment: Just to clarify your question a bit, you're interested in displaying a nested attribute, `organisation_branch` inside the Serializer, right? This is a question about getting those details in the serializer?

Comment: @VeridianDynamics yes I need the organisation branch details along with the city name not jus the city id

Comment: What have you attempted to solve the problem?

Comment: @max I am planning to have a separate serializer for organisation_branch, from which I will get the city_id and retrieve from the City table. I wanted to know the best optimal solution to do this